# Ошибка в запросе: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: php, sql, oracle

При генереции запроса к БД Oracle с помощью PHP получается вот такой результат:

```
UPDATE MYTEST2 SET DESCRIPTION = 'Буmvo', 
NAME = 'ris' 
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'Буmv';
UPDATE MYTEST2 SET DESCRIPTION = 'briz', 
NAME = 'Gilio' 
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'briz';
```

Но он не выполняется и возвращается ошибка:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я мог допустить ошибку?

Функция для формирования запроса:

```php
//Редактировать таблицу
public static function editTable(){

    //

    //
    //$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
    //$namesc - имя столбца
    // $namesc = $_POST['id_name'];
    // //Новое значение
    // $text = $_POST['new_val'];
    $testArray = [];

    if(isset($_POST['oll_items'])){

        //Новые значения строки
        $allIrems = $_POST['oll_items'];

        //столбец и значение будут использованы в кочесве индетификатора
        $columnAndValue = $_POST['clumn_value'];

        //Наименование таблицы
        $table = $_POST['cr_table'];

        //Заголовоки таблицы
        // $headerTable = $_POST['cr_header'];

        //Подключаемся к БД
        global $conn;
        $query = "UPDATE $table SET ";

        $query2 = "UPDATE $table SET ";
        $result = "";
        //Изменение данных в таблице

        foreach ($allIrems as $item) {
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                if(!next($item)){
                    $query .= $key . " = \"" . $value . "\" \n";
                }else{
                    $query .= $key . " = \"" . $value . "\", \n";
                }
            }
            $query .= " WHERE ";
            foreach ($columnAndValue as $i) {
                foreach ($i as $key => $value) {
                        $query .= "$key = \"$value\"";
                }
                array_shift($columnAndValue);
                break;
            }
            //$result .= $query . ";\n";

            // $result = str_replace("'", '', $result);
            // $result = str_replace('"', "'", $result);

            $query = str_replace("'", '', $query);
            $query = str_replace('"', "'", $query);
            // return $query;
            $stip = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $res = oci_execute($stip);
            $query = "";
            $query = $query2;
}
```

Выполнение запроса в SQL*Plus:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Har 29 10:44:03 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.   All rights reserved.

Enter user-naae: system Enter password:

Last Successful login tiae: Tue Har 29 2016 16:38:47 403:00 Connected to:
Oracle Oatabase 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> UPDATE HVTEST2 SET DESCRIPTION = 'aaa',  NAME =  'bbb' WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'ccc';UPOATE HYTEST2 SET DESCRIPTION =  'briz",  NAME  =  'Gilio' WHERE DESCRIPTI ON = 'briz';
UPDATE HYTEST2 SET DESCRIPTION = 'aaa',  NAME =  'bbb' WHERE DESCRIPTION = *6yw v';UPOATE HVTEST2 SET DESCRIPTION =  'briz',  NAME  =  'Gilio' WHERE DESCRIPTION = " briz"

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL coawiand not properly ended
SQL>_
```

Comment: А вы это через что выполняете ? Я вижу тут два отдельных запроса, которые надо отдавать ораклу отдельными вызовами функции. И точка с запятой в конце при этом не нужна

Comment: С помощью цикла foreach. Если нужен код функции реализующий данный запрос, добавлю.

Comment: Т.е. по одному update вызываете за раз и точек с запятой при этом нет ? Да, лучше кусок кода, который вызывает update приведите. Потому как сами запросы синтаксически верны

Comment: Распечатайте получающийся запрос и попробуйте его выполнить в каком нибудь sql plus. Запросы которые вы приводите вверху, для примера точно рабочие. Такая ошибка как у вас получается может быть только если в запрос включено что то совершенно неожиданное по синтаксису или не включено что то необходимое

Comment: Пробовал... ошибка.

Comment: Возвращаемся к тому, что я написал самым первым комментарием. Вы пытаетесь выполнить несколько update за один раз. Вы можете выполнять их только по одному. `UPDATE MYTEST2 SET DESCRIPTION = 'Буmvo', 
NAME = 'ris' 
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'Буmv'` все, вот на этом надо остановится, возможно добавить точку с запятой или `/` что бы sql plus это выполнил. Вот так как вы это делаете по несколько update практически слитно вы конечно получите ту ошибку какую получаете

Comment: Все разобрался, добавил в конец запроса "\n"( $query .= "$key = \"$value\"\n";) и все заработало. Благодарю Вас Mike!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Очень частое заблуждение по поводу "точка с запятой" (`;`) и связанной с ним ошибки:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Что по поводу [этого символа сказано в вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax):

> SQL statements also include the semicolon (";") statement terminator.
> **Though not required on every platform**, it is defined as a standard part of the SQL grammar.

Oracle SQL это как раз та платформа, которая этот пункт стандарта по исторически сложившимся причинам игнорирует. То есть, если например сравнить с некоторыми другими ЯП, то строка кода:

```
int i = 0; String s = "abc";
```

содержит два законченных выражения включая символы `;`, то валидное выражение:

```
select some_col from some_table;
```

заканчивается **последним символом до** `;`. Символ `;` служит указанием клиентской программе или библиотеке, послать весь текст запроса **до точки с запятой** парсеру SQL на сервер БД.

Другими словами, символ `;` является недействительным в SQL синтаксисе Oracle БД. Если он встретится при парсинге SQL запроса, то это приведёт к выше указаной или другим ошибкам.

Заключение, так делать нельзя:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual; select 2 from dual;
select 1 from dual; select 2 from dual
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Обратите внимание, как клиентская программа "поняла" введённые комманды: последний `;` удалён и текст запроса с `;` в середине послан серверу БД как один запрос.